# Compact set of infinitely many irrational numbers

Tags: real-analysis

What is a set of infinitely many irrational numbers that is also compact?

Comment: $\{1/n+\sqrt 2: n\in\Bbb N\}\cup\{\sqrt2\}$. You could also construct an uncountable Cantor set with no rationals.

Comment: @DavidMitra I don't believe that set is compact - you need to include $\sqrt{2}$. (Consider the open set $U_n=({1\over n}-{1\over 2n^2}, {1\over n}+{1\over 2n^2}).$)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Oh yes, thanks...

Comment: To the OP: what have you tried, and where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a nice fact: suppose $C$ is a compact set with empty interior (like the Cantor set). Then there is a translate of $C$ - that is, a set of the form $C+r=\{c+r: c\in C\}$ - such that $C$ contains no rationals.

The proof of this is via the Baire category theorem. For $q\in\mathbb{Q}$, let $$A_q=\{r: q\not\in C+r\}.$$ Since $C$ is closed, $A_q$ is open, and since $C$ has empty interior $A_q$ is dense. Finally, since there are only countably many rationals, this means $$B=\bigcap_{q\in\mathbb{Q}} A_q$$ is dense by Baires category theorem, hence not empty. Let $b\in B$; then $C+b$ contains no rationals (do you see why?).

Of course, there are examples not involving the Baire category theorem, but this is a very useful fact to know.

Comment: Two answers for the price of one! (I’m working through my backlog, so I saw the other question first.) I’m lazy: when I see this question my first thought is always that $2^\omega\subseteq\omega^\omega$.

Answer (score 1):

Try 
$$
K=\{\pi\}\cup\Big\{\frac{n}{n+1}\pi\,\big|\,
n=1,2,\ldots\Big\}
$$